# How to prove that $a + b + c + √3 \geq 8abc(\frac{1}{a^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} + \frac{1}{c^2 + 1})$ when $ab + bc + ca \geq 1$?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

So here is the Question :-

> How to prove that $$a + b + c + √3 \geq 8abc(\frac{1}{a^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} + \frac{1}{c^2 + 1})$$ where $a,b,c\geq 0$ are such that$ab + bc + ca \leq 1$ ?

What I tried :- I took the $$(\frac{1}{a^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} + \frac{1}{c^2 + 1})$$ part to the left hand side ,  and got $$(a + b + c + √3)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 3) \geq 8abc$$

I already knew that $(a + b)(b + c)(c + a) \geq 8abc$ (which can be proved by AM-GM inequality) , so if i can able to show that :-

$$(a + b + c + √3)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 3) \geq (a + b)(b + c)(c + a) \geq 8abc$$ , I am done .
But now I don't know how to proceed further , or I am not sure whether  $$(a + b + c + √3)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 3) \geq (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)$$ is really true or not , in that case the proof won't work . Also I did not even use the fact that $ab + bc + ca \leq 1$ .

Can anyone help me on this ? Hints or Suggestions will be greatly appreciated ! .

**Edit 01**:- As @Muhammad Zuhair Khan mentioned out, transferring $(\frac{1}{a^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{b^2+1} + \frac{1}{c^2 + 1})$ to the LHS side does not give $(a + b + c + √3)(a^2 + b^2+ c^2 + 3)$ . So my approach was wrong only .

Comment: $\frac 1a +\frac 1b \neq \frac 1{a+b}$. Your first line was wrong.

Comment: yeah right , so my approach was totally wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong. Try $a=b=c=1$.

We obtain: $$3+\sqrt3\geq12,$$ which is wrong.

But for $ab+ac+bc\leq1$ it's true.

If so, we need to prove that:
$$a+b+c+\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\geq8abc\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(a+b)(a+c)}$$ or
$$(a+b+c)\prod_{cyc}(a+b)+\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq16abc(a+b+c),$$ which is true because by AM-GM
$$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq8abc$$ and since $$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$$ it's just $$\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0,$$ by AM-GM again we obtain:
$$\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)^3}\geq8abc(a+b+c).$$

Comment: And after all this time I tried to prove the inequality...

Comment: oh thanks @Michael Rozenburg , there was a mistake in copying down the question , you can read it now

Comment: @Maths-Lover With $ab+ac+bc\leq1$ it's true.

Comment: yes , the question just meant that only

Comment: Can you explain me the part which you think is obvious?

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @Maths-Lover You are welcome!